# Unable to find module 'prompt-sync'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, user-input, npm-install

I am trying to take under input in nodejs using prompt but it shows me the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'prompt-sync'
Require stack:
- D:\Code\C++\Concepts\conditionals.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code\C++\Concepts\conditionals.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\Code\\C++\\Concepts\\conditionals.js' ]
}
```

I have installed '*prompt-sync*' using *npm* but the issue still persists.
This is my code:

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
let num = prompt("Enter your age: ");
console.log(typeof num);
```

I have tried restarting my pc and updated nodejs to its latest version(currently 9.2.0).

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your installed node modules like so:

```
npm cache verify
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

rm works if you are under linux or gitbash on Windows. If not delete the node_modules folder and the package.lock.json. (not the package.json)

When executing the npm i, take a look if error messages comes. Not all npm packages are combatiple with all node versions.

Controll in your package.json if the prompt-sync module is in the dependency section. If not reinstall it. You need to be inside your project folder when you install a module.